# Is there some way to open common documents like (DOC, XLS, PPT)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I looked a lot at a library or any way to open the most common documents like (DOC, XLS, PPT).
What I really need is to pass the uri into a specific to viewer these files in my application "As I do not need to use Intent", is there any way or library to open these files?
The important is only reading the files

Comment: Just did a quick google search. Not sure if this meets expectation https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: "what I really need is to pass the uri into a specific to viewer these files" -- you can launch a viewer using an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: CommonsWare : Thak you but I want view file in my activity